# How To Install JAVA EE in Ubuntu 11.04 properly?

Tags: java, jdk

I am totally new to Ubuntu and just installed it for the first time. I am trying to install JAVA EE in my ubuntu. I downloaded it from oracle website and its an .sh file. I followed instructions from this website on how to run .sh files: http://ma65p.wordpress.com/2008/08/03/how-to-deal-with-sh-files-in-ubuntu/. Whenever I hit enter in the terminal it says: `Could not locate a suitable jar utility.
Please ensure that you have Java 6 or newer installed on your system
and accessible in your PATH or by setting JAVA_HOME.`
 Please help...

Comment: i answered a similar question yesterday ,  http://askubuntu.com/questions/799315/how-to-install-jdk1-2-beside-jdk1-8/799332?noredirect=1#comment1205220_799332  i hope this will help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just `sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-jre` ?
Or install the `sun-java6-jdk` / `sun-java6-jre` packages with synaptic?

After it finishes try `java -version` to test it is installed.

Comment: Is it JAVA EE ?

Comment: Oh, alright, try to execute that sh after installing jre.

Comment: Also, take a look here for additional info (not necessarily ubuntu-based) [Problems installing Java EE SDK on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224321/problems-installing-java-ee-sdk-on-linux)