# How to install jdk1.2 beside jdk1.8

Tags: java, jdk

I am new to linux and ubuntu... I am trying to run a program which is old (2001), in the MakeFile it says the `javac` is jdk1.2 (or 1.3), however I already isntalled `javac 9-internal`.

Can I yet install a javac of jdk1.2 beside this java to make the program?
In general what is the solution to run such older projects?

Answer (score 1):

yes , that's quite easy, just download the jdk, extract it somewhere and set path in your .bashrc file like below

```
# User specific aliases and functions
JAVA_HOME=/mnt/install/jdk1.8.0_77
JRE_HOME=/mnt/install/jdk1.8.0_77/bin


export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME:$MAVEN/bin:$PATH
```

then close and open terminal again or do this

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Thanks, can I get jdk1.2 using `apt-get`?

Comment: if you want to keep two versions than, it won't be possible as per my knowledge, also manually installation gives you full access of where to store it.